# Merge with Nested Tables. ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a PL/SQL procedure in which I create and populate a nested table using dynamic SQL.

I later want to use this nested table to update information in another table using a `MERGE`.

Declarations look somewhat like this:

```
TYPE row_type IS RECORD (
   a db_table.a%type,
   b db_table.b%type,
   c db_table.c%type
);

TYPE nested_type IS TABLE OF row_type INDEX BY INTEGER;

nested_table nested_type;
```

The table is then populated with some dynamic SQL

The MERGE looks something like that:

```
MERGE INTO db_table t
USING table(nested_table) nt ON (t.a = nt.a AND t.b = nt.b)

WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN
       UPDATE 
           SET c = nt.c,
               d = nt.d

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
   THEN
       INSERT (a, b, c, d)
       VALUES (nt.a, nt.b, nt.c, nt.d);
```

Table 'db_table' has the columns a, b, c, d, e and f, while 'nested_table' only has columns a, b, c and d.

When I run the procedure, I get an error

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

How would I go about fixing this issue? Is it even possible to merge from a nested table into another table?

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be with the following part:

```
MERGE into db_table t
USING table(nested_table) nt
```

If I replace table(nested_table) with the table I use to populate the nested table, the procedure runs fine.

Comment: Can you share the table specs? Might be mismatched datatypes Oracle is trying to reconcile

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include how you declare the nested table data type and whether you have declared it in SQL using `CREATE TYPE ...` or if you have declared it in PL/SQL using `TYPE ...`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to merge from a nested table into another table?

Yes, your code works and does not need fixing.

---

Declare an object type and a collection type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE obj_type IS OBJECT(
  a INT,
  b INT,
  c INT,
  d INT
);

CREATE TYPE obj_table IS TABLE OF obj_type;
```

Then create a table (this is an object-derived table but a standard table declaration would also work) and add some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE db_table OF obj_type;

INSERT INTO db_table (a,b,c,d)
SELECT 1 As a, 1 AS b, 1 AS c, 1 AS d FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Then run your query (using an anonymous PL/SQL block to define the `nested_table` variable):

```sql
DECLARE
  nested_table obj_table := obj_table(
    obj_type(1,1,2,3),
    obj_type(3,3,6,9),
    obj_type(4,4,8,12)
  );
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO db_table t
  USING TABLE(nested_table) nt
  ON (t.a = nt.a AND
      t.b = nt.b)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET c = nt.c,
        d = nt.d
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (a, b, c, d)
    VALUES (nt.a, nt.b, nt.c, nt.d);
END;
/
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 | 12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BzBbb8GR)